# How to disable night mode in my application even if night mode is enable in android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-dark-theme

i want to disable dark mode in my application(Android Q) .. i tired many ways not yet getting solution for this . could you please suggest perfect solution for this.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line to your styles xml. That'll remove the forced dark option

```
 <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Comment: does the app colors change when you turn off the dark mode? I tried many methods and this one was the only thing that worked for me. Is your AppTheme extend from Theme.AppCompat.Light ?               <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Comment: yes app color change when i turn off the dark mode..i applied  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> this one also not working for me..anything need to add in manifest or some other activity ?

Comment: Nope I just referenced it in the manifest under application-> android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: yeah i added same like what u mention above

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can disable it either for all over the app with the line in the onCreate

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

or just for a single Activity:

```
getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

after that you will need to recreate() in order to use it again.